# Why is my 'view selected' lighting different than my scene lighting?

Tags: lighting

The lighting when i press '/' to view selected is perfect and i want to keep this lighting however it is different from my actual scene lighting and i'm not sure how the 'view selected' lighting is calculated but i like it. The lighter blue object is the one i am after. thanks!

[image: actual scene desired view selected lightinglighting]

[image: view selected lighting]

Comment: Pressing / on the Numpad is switching to _Local_ view. What this means is, Blender shows you only those objects which were selected while you pressed /. It is like making all other objects invisible temporarily (Not only that, you can also rotate the view angle etc. without changing it in the normal view). So since the object in the bottom screenshot looks brighter, I guess you have a light source in your scene. If the light isn't selected when pressing / it will not be taken into _Local_ view and so it will not brighten up your object.

Comment: Thank you! This led to me understanding what was causing the issue. Turn out i had a duplicate of the object which was darkening my main object and that was disappearing when i went into Local View so it looked like the lighting had changed, thanks!

Comment: Ah, glad you solved it. So it was local view... it would be best to post complete screenshots if you are not sure what to look for. In this case the word "Local" in the top left of the 3D Viewport would have been a hint for us trying to help 